# DataContract SerializationException when using list of predicates

Tags: c#, serialization, datacontractserializer

I'm writing a generic filter class that will be primarily used to filter persons from a population. I'm trying to serialize the filter class, but at runtime I get an SerializationException:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException : Type 'System.DelegateSerializationHolder+DelegateEntry' with data contract name 'DelegateSerializationHolder.DelegateEntry:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.
```

My filter class looks like this:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Filter", Namespace = "")]
    public class Filter<T>
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Default constructor, needed by serializers.
        /// </summary>
        public Filter()
        {
            Name = "New filter";
            Predicates = new List<Predicate<T>>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// ctor. Takes a list of predicates for type T
        /// to filter with.  
        /// </summary>
        public Filter(string name, IEnumerable<Predicate<T>> predicates)
        {
            Name = name;
            Predicates = predicates.ToList();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Name of the filter. 
        /// </summary>
        [DataMember(Order = 0)]
        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [DataMember(Order = 1)]
        public List<Predicate<T>> Predicates
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Filters sequence of type T. 
        /// </summary>
        public IEnumerable<T> ApplyFilter(IEnumerable<T> input)
        {
            var result = new List<T>(input);
            return Predicates.Aggregate(result, (current, predicate) => current.FindAll(predicate));
        }
    }
```

When serializing the filter class, I get the above exception. If I don't mark the Predicate as a DataMember, then it works. But obviously I want to serialize that property as well.

I've been at this for a couple of hours now, and I can't figure it out. Any helps would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DataContractSerializer` is not intended for serializing delegates; a multi-cast delegate is a set of arbitrary target objects and methods; this is **not** a well-defined data-oriented contract. `DataContractSerializer` is intended for *data*.

Either serialize some form of expression *as a string* (or some simple tree), or use a different serializer.

Comment: Thanks. What serializer can I use for delegates?

Comment: @tobier frankly, most serializers **don't want to do this**, because delegates are *implementation*, not *data*. Most serializers are interested in *data*. The only one I know that is really geared for that is `BinaryFormatter`. Please don't mistake that as a *recommendation*. You could try `NetDataContractSerializer`, which is very similar (essentially) to `BinaryFormatter`. Again, not a recommendation. My recommendation is: serialize **data**.

Comment: Any recommendations on how to store this class? I want to be able to store these filters that are made up of delegates in, say, a "filters.xml", so that they can be used in the future. The filters are created by the users in the application.

Comment: @tobier would a string expression suffice? i.e. "x.Foo == 12 && x.IsOpen"

Comment: @tobier some; I don't have any particular recommendations, but it is quite a common question

Comment: @tobier I deliberately didn't mention those... They don't serialize very nicely...

Answer (score 0):

Not trying to resurrect a dead post, but I searched for (basically) the same error message and this question is currently the #1 result, but I'm not trying to do anything with delegates!

Couldn't figure out what I was doing wrong, until I found [this post](https://qa.social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bda6bee2-cb52-4cb9-b96c-f00676eca9f5/there-was-an-error-while-trying-to-serialize-parameter-httptempuriorgr?forum=wcf) on the MSDN forums. The answer is:

> I found that when I added DataContract and DataMember to my class things worked.

*facepalm*

I was trying to serialize a custom class, but didn't tag that class with the `[DataContract]` attribute and, for reasons I don't understand, that caused the XML serializer to throw the error about delegates.

Posting this answer to help all the future visitors. *Socially distant high-five from the age of coronavirus!*

Comment: I think what you do these days is at most bump elbows. Who'd think eight years ago we'd be working from home due to a pandemic, crazy times.

Comment: @tobier - We do "air high-fives" here lol - mime a high-five while standing 6+ feet apart.