# How to prevent serialization of delegates when using DataContractSerializer?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, serialization, xml-serialization

I have a couple of entity classes autogenerated by Linq2Sql. I want to have a possibility to serialize them using DataContractSerializer. But when I'm trying to do that I'm getting an exception because DataContractSerializer can't serialize delegates. As I need to serialize only data, I want to exclude delegates from serialization process. How can I do that?

I can't do that using attributes, because the classes are autogenerated.

Comment: Are you saying that Linq2Sql is auto-generating delegates which the DataContractSerializer is trying to serialize?  What kind of delegates?

Comment: there are event handlers. I got an exception like described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612737/datacontract-serializationexception-when-using-list-of-predicates

Answer (score 3):

LINQ2SQL auto-generated classes are not POCO. AFAIK, they even not marked with `DataContract` attributes and contains a lot of stuff, which will be a pain for `DataContractSerializer`.

Create your own DTOs and serialize them. This will be more efficient.